# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined - Implementing new feature

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I've followed a MERN tutorial for a blog and everything went fine, now I am trying to add a podcast page alongside the blog, I copied all of the views and components from the blog and changed everything to podcast. I am able to create a podcast, view the podcast when I type the specific URL as it adds fine to mongo, however when I goto view the podcast page I am receiving the below error...

'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'videoPodcast')' also 'The above error occurred in the  component:'

```
import "./podcast.css"
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"
import { Fade } from "react-awesome-reveal";

export default function Podcast({podcast}) {
  let moment = require ('moment');

  // const PF = "http://localhost:5000/images/"
  return (
<div className="podcastFront">
      {podcast.videoPodcast && (
        // <img class="postImg" src={PF + post.photo/} alt="" />
        <Link to = {`/podcast/${podcast._id}`} className="link"><img class="podcastImg" src={podcast.videoPodcast} alt="" /></Link>
      )}
        <div className="podcastInfo">
            {/* <div className="postCats">{
              post.categories.map(c=> (
                <span className="postCat">ssdasdsa{c.name}</span>
              ))
            }
            // </div> */}
            <Link to = {`/podcast/${podcast._id}`} className="link">
            <span className="podcastTitle">{podcast.titlePodcast}
            </span>
            </Link>
        <span className="podcastDate">{moment(podcast.createdAt).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')}</span>
        </div>
        <p className="podcastDesc">{podcast.descPodcast}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

and

```
import Podcast from "../podcast/Podcast"
import "./podcasts.css"

export default function Podcasts({podcasts}) {
  return (
    <div className="podcasts">
      {podcasts.map((p)=>(
        <Podcast podcast={p} />
      ))}
        </div>
  )
}
```

Could someone please help me? As I have no idea as I have copied everything from the blog section so not sure what the problem could be?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incomplete as you haven't provided from where the component Podcasts is called in the below code

```
import Podcast from "../podcast/Podcast"
import "./podcasts.css"

export default function Podcasts({podcasts}) {
  return (
    <div className="podcasts">
      {podcasts.map((p)=>(
        <Podcast podcast={p} />
      ))}
        </div>
  )
}
```

and also the schema of props -->{podcasts}  needs to be showed clearly for understanding the problem as if there any key/object named videoPodcast is present  in object podcasts or not  .